# Find riak node's listening HTTP and Protobuf port

Tags: linux, networking, database, database-administration

I recently followed and scripted the Riak 5 minute install, successfully getting 4 nodes running on a Ubuntu 14.04 VM.  Currently the nodes are running and are joined / clustered successfully.

running `riak-admin member-status` on any node details:

```
================================= Membership ==================================
Status     Ring    Pending    Node
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
valid      25.0%      --      'dev1@127.0.0.1'
valid      25.0%      --      'dev2@127.0.0.1'
valid      25.0%      --      'dev3@127.0.0.1'
valid      25.0%      --      'dev4@127.0.0.1'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Valid:4 / Leaving:0 / Exiting:0 / Joining:0 / Down:0
```

Inorder to connect my middleware client I need to know the port numbers for each listening port.

`Netstat -tulpn` lists a large amount of beam.smp processes, and doesn't help narrow down to individual nodes.

Is there a command that can be used to retrieve this information on each node?

Any help / assistance appreciated.

Comment: Created the tag for you since other database engines have their own tags.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Riak 2.0 + you can use the following to list out the listeners with port numbers:

```
riak config effective | grep listener
```

sample output:

```
listener.http.internal = 192.168.10.1:9098
listener.protobuf.internal = 192.168.10.1:9097
```